# How to checkbox in gridview got checked when you write text on textbox

Tags: asp.net

How to make checkbox checked = true in gridview when you write text on textbox?

This is my code of what I am trying:

```
 protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
           foreach (GridViewRow row in gvTeacherPage.Rows)

          {

         CheckBox chbAbsence = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chbAbsence");

     if (connect.checkStudentNo(int.Parse(TextBox1.Text)) == true && TextBox1 .Text !=   "")
           {    chbAbsence.CheckedChanged += new  EventHandler(chbAbsence_CheckedChanged); 

     if (connect.checkStudentNo(int.Parse(TextBox1.Text)) == false && TextBox1.Text ==  "")
                  {                       
                chbAbsence.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chbAbsence_CheckedChanged);
                  }
              }
            ShowAlertMessage("process completed successfully");

            ddlCourseName_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null); 

            TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    }

// this is checking event
  private void chbAbsence_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox ;
        if (!chk.Checked)
            chk.Checked = true;
        else
            chk.Checked = false;
    }
```

Comment: just use javascript for that task. can you provide your html markup so I can help you?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not going to work as you might expect it to.

Gridviews (and DataGrids) have postback issues with checkboxes and radiobuttons; you can set the AutoPostBack property to true and handle the grid ItemCommand, expecting to get that event raised when you check or uncheck a checkbox inside the grid, but because the checkbox and radiobutton controls do not have CommandName or CommandArgument properties, they will never fire ItemCommand.

Your approach (assigning an event handler dynamically) will not work either. However, it can be done. The trick is to examine the form POST variable '__EVENTTARGET' in Page Init/Load, looking for the name of your checkbox control. If this form variable (which ASP.NET generates) contains the name of your control, then it was the one which was checked/unchecked.

(Of course within a GridView or DataGrid, WebForms is going to mangle the ID of the control, and there's potentially going to be several of them; that is why you do a CONTAINS search)

The following gives an example; it's from a DataGrid but will be trivial to convert to a GridView.

in Page Load: -

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // do whatever when page first loads
    }
    else
    {
        TestForCheckedChanged();
    }
}
```

the method itself: -

```
private void TestForCheckedChanged()
{
    if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != null)
    {
        string target = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"];

        // check for the name of your control
        if (target.Contains("chkSelect"))
        {
            // got one - do a Page.FindControl on the actual name, which will be 
            // something like ctl00_row1_chkSelect11 or something similar
            var chk = Page.FindControl(target) as CheckBox;

            if (chk != null)
            {
                // from here you can get to the datagrid/view item
                var item = chk.BindingContainer as DataGridItem;
                // note; my example assumes an integer ID is used as the grid DataKeyField
                int key  = Convert.ToInt32(grid.DataKeys[item.ItemIndex]);

                // from here, can get any other controls in that grid row
                var txt = grid.Items[key].FindControl("txtSomething");

                // you can also get the value of the checkbox itself; 'on' is checked
                if (Request.Form[target] == "on")
                {
                    // do something because checkbox was checked
                }
                else
                {
                    // do something because checkbox was unchecked
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Give that a try, let me know if you need any help.

Comment: sorry if you didn't get my question. the Textbox is out of the gridview and I need to write numeric value in it then it will be checked whether its true or false then if true checkbox will be checked true otherwise will be unchecked (false) that's the point sir